# How to swap words after specific word, which can be in one line or can be in differen lines using sed?

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I have a file where line starts :

```
OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12).     SUNNY 
OCCUPY 45 EVERY PIC X(21).      SUNNY
```

and some lines can split in two rows :

```
1      OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12).    SUNNY
2              OCCUPY 45 EVERY        SUNNY 
3                   PIC X(21).        SUNNY
```

And desired output is :

```
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.    SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.     SUNNY
```

So, I need to bring the separated lines into one row and swap the words as well . 
So, for the ones which are in one row, I am using command :

```
sed 's/\(OCCUPY.*EVERY\) *\(PIC *[^ }*\)\./\2 \1./'
```

```
sed -Ez 's/(OCCUPY)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(EVERY)\s+(PIC)\s+([^)]+\))/\4 \5 \1 \2 \3/g'
```

These commands are working, but only if the line is in one row and also it shifting the word SUNNY and the dot is one space away. The word SUNNY must be in one same field. So, the incorrect output is :

```
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.     SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY .   SUNNY
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `perl -pe 'unless (/\.\s*\z/) { $_ .= readline; redo } s/^OCCUPY\s+(\S+)\s+EVERY\s+(\S.*)\./$2 OCCUPY $1 EVERY./'`?

Comment: You're not using the sed command you say you are as it contains syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed for `-E`, `-z`, and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(OCCUPY\s+[0-9]+\s+EVERY)\s+(PIC\s+[^)]+\))/\2 \1/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.
```

and if every line fits that pattern of space/non-space strings you can reduce that to:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/((\S+\s+){2}\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+\))/\3 \1/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.
```

or if the line can be split at any white space, not just where shown in your example:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(OCCUPY)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(EVERY)\s+(PIC)\s+([^)]+\))/\4 \5 \1 \2 \3/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.

$ sed -Ez 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+\))/\4 \5 \1 \2 \3/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.
```

---

Given your updated input/output the scripts still work:

```
$ cat file
OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12).     SUNNY
OCCUPY 45 EVERY
        PIC X(21).      SUNNY

$ sed -Ez 's/(OCCUPY\s+[0-9]+\s+EVERY)\s+(PIC\s+[^)]+\))/\2 \1/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.     SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.      SUNNY

$ sed -Ez 's/((\S+\s+){2}\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+\))/\3 \1/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.     SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.      SUNNY

$ sed -Ez 's/(OCCUPY)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(EVERY)\s+(PIC)\s+([^)]+\))/\4 \5 \1 \2 \3/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.     SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.      SUNNY

$ sed -Ez 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+\))/\4 \5 \1 \2 \3/g' file
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY.     SUNNY
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY.      SUNNY
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I was trying the code you provided me, but the thing is it is shifting the order and the dot is one space ahead, is it possible not to change them? I updated the output on my question. Can you please take a look ? Thank you

Comment: Its very important when asking questions about parsing/manipulating text to provide truly representative sample input/output. You shouldn't expect scripts written for one input format to work for another. Having said that, the scripts in my answer do still work for your new input format too. See the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: Hang on - are you saying the word "SUNNY" suddenly appears mid-record when your input record is split across lines?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Ed. I really appreciate them. 
The thing is on each row in every 73 field, there is a word SUNNY, and it should always be in one field. So whenever I write a new line, I have to also include SUNNY on the field 73 .
And on your input, you didn't specify SUNNY near OCCUPY 45 EVERY. It supposed to be in every field.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about there being fields previously. If there are tab-separated or fixed-width or any other kind of fields and the wrapping text is in one field then that completely changes the problem and it will certainly be better handled with an awk rather than sed solution. Please create a new question with **truly** representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: Okay, I will create a new question. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/OCCUPY/{:a;/ PIC/!{N;s/\n\s*//;ta};s/PIC/\n&/;s/(.*) \n([^.]*)/\2 \1/}' file
```

This focuses on lines that contain `OCCUPY` and then if that same line does not also contain `PIC` appends further lines (removing their newlines) until it does.

Using an introduced newline as a delimiter, it then uses pattern matching to re-arrange the line in the pattern space to the required format.